# inline-block fluid layout, child content will not expand parent container

Tags: css, height, overflow, parent-child, fluid-layout

I asked a question earlier on here pertaining to a fluid 3 column layout I'm developing in a custom drupal front page and contributors suggested I switch from absolute container divs that use margins to dynamically resize to something else - I chose **display:inline-block**. (I hate floats and table cells seem like a step backwards)

I was able to evenly space my three divs no problem and even get the 100% height of the children to match the parent height when I specify a percentage height on all parent divs.

HOWEVER content in the child divs won't push the page wrapper div down so it overflows into and past the footer. if I set **overflow:auto** on the wrapper div, then it displays correctly BUT I get a scrollbar on the wrapper div which I do not want.

If I remove the height value from the page wrapper, child content expands the page wrapper as it should BUT I lose all my heights on my child divs!!!

is there some hack to make this work (or am I missing something) as I need it to or am I stuck doing it another way? I tried **min-height:xx%** and it doesn't work.

```
    <div id="page-div">
     <div id="inline-wrapper">
      <div id="top-content">
       <div id="left">user picture, links</div>
       <div id="center">blah blah blah blah blah</div>
       <div id="right">user picture, links</div>
      </div>
      <div id="a nav menu"></div>
      <div id="main-content">
       <div id="left">user picture, links</div>
       <div id="center">blah blah blah blah blah</div>
       <div id="right">user picture, links</div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>

html, body {height:100%}
#page-div {height:100%;width:80%;margin:0 auto;}
#inline-wrapper {height:100%;width:100%;background-color:#fff;}
#top-content {height:100%; width:98%;}
#top-content div {vertical-align:top;}
#left, #center, #right {display:inline-block;height:100%;}
#left, #right {width:13%;background-color:#000;}
#center {width:74%;}
#footer {height:250px;width:100%;margin-top:3%;}
```

Comment: can I do something with the :before or :after classes?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you want here I made a jsfiddle with your code using `inline-block` (without any hight set): http://jsfiddle.net/ZYU4c/ and here is another example where i use positioning absolute on the left and right column ... so that they can fill the hight: http://jsfiddle.net/LrFzj/1.

Comment: It would be good to make your layout needs clearer. For example, how do you want the footer to behave, and will there be content between the columns and the footer? Don't be spooked by the notion of CSS "table layout", either. It has nothing to do with using tables in your layouts. Rather, it is one more CSS device for making things work on screen.

Comment: to your comment Rich: of course you can also do something with the pseudo elements (:before and :after), if toi position them absolutely, behind the columns, you can pretend the columns stretch over the whole hight (http://jsfiddle.net/ZYU4c/1/), but as Ralph sais, the approach depends on what exactly you want the outcome to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too sure table is not appropriate, it does exectly what you want, it takes 100%, and grow pushdown everything .

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/hsEbJ  (display-table used for it's ability to grow from any given heigth)

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/udvgj  (display:inline-block that pushes not much if height is given :) )

```
element {display:inline-block;}
            /* or ? */
element {display:table;}
```

In fact (IMHO), display and float exists and each values gives different behavior, they should be chosen where you need them and not if it's 'hype' or 'has been' .
 Vintage is cool ;) .

display:flex will put order soon :)

Comment: what I am looking for is a completely responsive site where it will grow vertically as more content is added to the child divs and push the footer down as it grows. your display:table looks great except you had to declare a height of 1700px. I'm looking for height to exclusively be a percentage.

Comment: the height is to show that it grows and push footer down, isn'it ? | remove it :) and add fake content in any of these 3 divs

Comment: I changed the center height to 100% and it works as I need it too ... am going to incorporate it into my site and see if it works with everything else put together. thanks!

Comment: glad i gave you some tips :)

Comment: I recoded the site using the framework you laid out - thank you! one problem; if I apply a 90% width for the inline wrapper div, to control the layout width, I cannot seem to center it in the page wrapper div. it goes to the far right. I do that because I have a logo image that overlaps the top of the inline wrapper :/

Comment: inline-block behaves like text :), text-align:center on parent.